# jqgrid update two tables from one grid

Tags: php, mysql, jqgrid

I have two tables in one grid displayed (via `LEFT JOIN`) and I wonder is there a way to implement an inline edit functionality for both table from the same grid?

I.e: 
when the main grid table updated:

```
onSuccess { table_name, {column1=value1,column2=value2,..}}
```

not necessarily above scenario - I'm seeking here for ideas and logic to it...

I know there is `setAfterCrudAction` function in `jqGridPHP` suit, but from the whole suit I only need this functionality... so I'm seeking to try to implement it myself with some help from you

any ideas appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Example](http://jqgrid-php.net/examples/?render=jqOperBasic) shows how to update fields when join is used (check 'PHP Grid' tab, btw [jqgrid-php](http://jqgrid-php.net/examples/) is free):

```
<?php

class jqOperBasic extends jqGrid
{
    protected function init()
    {
        $this->table = 'tbl_order_item';

        $this->query = "
            SELECT {fields}
            FROM tbl_order_item i
                JOIN tbl_books b ON (i.book_id=b.id)
            WHERE {where}
        ";

        #Set columns
        $this->cols = array(

            'item_id' => array('label' => 'ID',
                'db' => 'i.id',
                'width' => 10,
                'align' => 'center',
                'formatter' => 'integer',
            ),

            'order_id' => array('label' => 'Order id',
                'db' => 'i.order_id',
                'width' => 15,
                'align' => 'center',
                'formatter' => 'integer',
            ),

            'name' => array('label' => 'Book name',
                'db' => 'b.name',
                'width' => 30,
                'editable' => true,
                'editrules' => array('required' => true),
            ),

            'price' => array('label' => 'Price',
                'db' => 'i.price',
                'width' => 15,
                'align' => 'center',
                'formatter' => 'integer',
                'editable' => true,
                'editrules' => array('required' => true,
                    'integer' => true,
                    'minValue' => 1,
                    'maxValue' => 3000
                ),
            ),
        );

        #Set nav
        $this->nav = array('edit' => true, 'edittext' => 'Edit');
    }

    #Save columns to different tables
    protected function opEdit($id, $upd)
    {
        #Server-side validation
        if(strlen($upd['name']) < 5)
        {
            #Just throw the exception anywhere inside the oper functions to stop execution and display error
            throw new jqGrid_Exception('The book name is too short!');
        }

        #Get editing row
        $result = $this->DB->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_order_item WHERE id=' . intval($id));
        $row = $this->DB->fetch($result);

        #Save book name to books table
        $this->DB->update('tbl_books', array('name' => $upd['name']), array('id' => $row['book_id']));
        unset($upd['name']);

        #Save other vars to items table
        $this->DB->update('tbl_order_item', $upd, array('id' => $id));
    }
}
```

Comment: oh great there is a free php layer... and i would be glad it's in Russian for anything else than programming or computing... can you please point me out to download source (hopefully that will be english-commented...)

Comment: https://github.com/wildraid/jqGridPHP/ "...English docs will be available soon." :) But you can follow examples - it is easy to make this lib running.

Comment: ok, I'll give it a try and let you know. thanks for suggestion

Comment: no examples of how to use it in index, nothing to say grid classes should be kept in grids folder (had to work it out from code), i cant get nav working, and it ignores JOINs in sql... shame... documentation needs to be much better (most of it looks outdated....)

Comment: You can easily manage complex output via view: prepare output in db and give to jqgrid just 1 object. Inserts/Updates/Deletes can be managed with triggers on view.

Comment: don't write joins in jqGrid, create them in db.